# Apply Gradient Colors on CarbonTapSwipeNavigation

Tags: ios, swift, carbonkit

I am new to iOS.I want to apply gradient colors on `CarbonTabSwipeNavigation`.I tried to apply the gradient to the toolbar of `CarbonTabSwipeNavigation`, but it is not working. Here's the code.

```
let carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: items, delegate: self)
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.toolbar.setGradientToToolbar(default_pri_color: UIColor.DarkBlue(), default_sec_color: UIColor.LightBlue())
```

Here's the Function

```
extension UIToolbar {

    func setGradientToToolbar(default_pri_color: UIColor, default_sec_color: UIColor) {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = [default_pri_color.cgColor, default_sec_color.cgColor]
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the `gradientLayer` frame. `Toolbar` constraints are not yet laid out when you are calling `setGradientToToolbar` method on it. So, with everything zero in `bounds` you are not able to see the gradient layer.

There are two ways to fix this,

**1)** You provide frame for `gradientLayer` as below,

```
func setGradientToToolbar(default_pri_color: UIColor , default_sec_color:UIColor) {
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 120)            
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
}
```

**2)** Call `setGradientToToolbar` method on toolbar after your `viewController` finishes layout for all views. Below is the complete example,

```
import UIKit
import CarbonKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CarbonTabSwipeNavigationDelegate {

    var carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let items = ["Features", "Products", "About"]
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: items, delegate: self)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.toolbarHeight.constant = 120
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.insert(intoRootViewController: self)
    }

    func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(_ carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAt index: UInt) -> UIViewController {
        return UIViewController()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.toolbar.setGradientToToolbar(default_pri_color: .red, default_sec_color: .yellow)
    }
}

extension UIToolbar {

    func setGradientToToolbar(default_pri_color: UIColor , default_sec_color:UIColor) {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = [default_pri_color.cgColor, default_sec_color.cgColor]
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Both will give you the below result,

[image]